# how to write R code that calculate correlation coefficient for 2 numbers

Tags: r, algorithm, correlation, mat

I have X = [2,3,5,10,8,5] Y = [7,6,9,1,6,3] variables I want to calculate correlation coefficient between them but without using "cor(X,Y)" function how can I achieve that?
[image]

Comment: yes you can use the formula @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use the formula, the `Xbar` is `mean`, `sigma` is `sum` and `sqrt` for the corresponding symbol in the formula

```
num1 <-  sum((X - mean(X))*(Y - mean(Y)))
den1 <- sqrt(sum((X - mean(X))^2) * sum((Y - mean(Y))^2))
num1/den1
[1] -0.599539
```

-testing with `cor`

```
cor(X, Y)
#[1] -0.599539
```

#### data

```
X <- c(2, 3, 5, 10, 8, 5)
Y <- c(7, 6, 9, 1, 6, 3)
```